# How to use associate arrays to get the id from the checkbox and appropreate value from the text field

Tags: php, checkbox, associative-array

[image: GUI]

Hi everyone, i'm new to programming. I need to develop a rating system with check boxes and text-fields where user clicks the subjects from the list and add his rating/experience in the text field. All these subjects and ratings are added to the database with the subject id and the rating. So the issue is, I don't know how to write the associate array to get the selected subjects and their appropriate rating to insert into the database. Can anyone please provide me some codes or samples similar to this. So, I can get some idea how to do this. Thanks in advance :)

This is the HTML sample code

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="372" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="24"><input type="checkbox" name="subid1" value="1" id="subid1"></td>
    <td width="203">Maths</td>`enter code here`
    <td width="145"><input type="text" name="sub1" id="sub1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subid2" value="2" id="subid2" /></td>
    <td>Physics</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subid2" id="subid2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subid3" value="3" id="subid3" /></td>
    <td>Computing</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subid3" id="subid3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subid4" value="4" id="subid4" /></td>
    <td>Chemistry</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subid4" id="subid4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subid5" value="5" id="subid5" /></td>
    <td>Biology</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subid5" id="subid5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="subid7" value="6" id="subid7" /></td>
    <td>Human Biology</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subid6" id="subid6" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you generate the HTML form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job on client side:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[myID1]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="t[myID1]" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[myID2]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="t[myID2]" value="" />
```

and this can be used on server side:

```
$usedTexts = array();
if ( array_key_exists("t", $_POST)  && is_array($_POST["t"])
  && array_key_exists("cb", $_POST) && is_array($_POST["cb"]) 
) 
{
  $usedTexts = array_intersect_key($_POST["t"], $_POST["cb"]);
}
```

see manual for server side: https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key

<sub>edit: fixed to POST; added array_key_exists() and is_array()</sub>

Comment: When I run your code. Following error shows

"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"

What might be the issue

Comment: Thanks. But still there are some errors in the code "Undefined index: t and cb" and "Warning: array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array" :(

Comment: How do you get your code to the server? whats the method of the <form> ? 
in my example it was 's GET. edited it to use POST
additionally you should check if $_POST["t"] and $_POST["cb"] are set and are ararys. use array_key_exists("t", $_POST) and is_array($_POST["t"]) for this.

Comment: method of the form is post

Comment: fixed the code to POST. also see my previous comment - it was edited